# What is wrong with this XAML only animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have a piece of XAML Code

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.XAMLOnly" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="XAMLOnly" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Center" Height="30"
                    Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox,Path = Text}" />
            <TextBox Name="textBox" Margin="5" Width="200" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Hello WPF!" />
            <Button Margin="5" Width="200" Content="Change Text Color">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1">
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidBrush.Color)" From="Black"
                                To="Red" Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </Button.Resources>
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource OnLoaded1}">
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It is giving the run time error
Provide value on "System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception

Why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` path you have written `SolidBrush` instead of `SolidColorBrush`.